# Extended Events, CPU_TIME

Tags: sql-server-2012, extended-events

I want to create a new session in Extended Events to track Queries that use lots of CPU_Time, but whats the Unit of CPU_TIME? ms? Microseconds?...

Duration seems to be Microseconds but I don't really know CPU_TIME and can't find any information regarding this...

Thanks,
Jimm

Comment: [CPU time is in miliseconds](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/tracking-expensive-queries-with-extended-events-in-sql-2008/) or [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saponsqlserver/2010/06/16/analyzing-statements-with-extended-events-extended-events-part-ii/)

Comment: I believe it is ms (i.e. millisecond)

Comment: I guess for "cpu_time rpc_completed NULL", it means microsecond. But why the description is NULL?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The sys.dm_xe_object_columns DMV shows metadata for each of the columns available for each event. Included is a "description" column, which is useful in answering your question.

```
select 
    name
    , object_name
    , type_name
    , description 
from
    sys.dm_xe_object_columns
where
    name = 'cpu_time' -- any XE column name here
```

This will show you all of the extended event objects that have a cpu_time column, and the description will tell you what unit of measure the column uses.

You can see here that units may vary depending on the object. For example:

- sql_statement_completed: Indicates the CPU time (in microseconds) that is consumed by the statement.
- sql_batch_completed: The CPU time (in milliseconds) used by the batch.

Comment: fwiw `cpu_time` for my SQL 2019 server is microseconds for ALL events except perhaps `vdw_statement_execution` and `vdw_backend_execution` where the description says 'CPU time (ms)'.